# Visual Studio cannot find the EntityModelCodeGenerator custom tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm helping develop a MVC application in Visual Studio 2008 using the Entity Model Framework.   I've gotten the code from the source control and I'm wanting to add some new Models from the edmx file. I right click and then click "Custom Tool" but then I get the following error.

**Cannot find custom tool 'EntityModelCodeGenerator' on this system.**

I have Visual Studio 2008, .NET 3.5 SP1, MVC 1.0.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need VS2008 SP1.

Comment: D'oh! Thanks a lot for the hit across the head.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Visual Studio 2019:

1. Open the Visual Studio Installer by clicking menu `Tools` -> `Get Tools and Features in Visual Studio`
2. Click the tab `Individual components` and search for "entity",
3. Under the header `SDKs, libraries, and frameworks` you should see `Entity Framework 6 tools`
4. Click the checkbox and press the install button

Comment: this helped me. the EF 6 tools item was already checked, just had to click the modify button and it was fixed