# Entity Framework not loading in Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, windows-7

I had to get a new machine recently.  It is Windows 7, loaded with Studio 2008, with Framework 3.5 sp1.  When I load pre-existing projects that use the Entity Framework, the projects don't recognize the .edmx files.  Any ideas?

I'm fully patched and running as administrator doesn't make a difference.

Opening as XML and saving I have managed to get the error " Cannot find the custom tool 'EntityModelCodeGenerator' on this system."  But I have all the updates and don't see any way to add this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396987/visual-studio-cannot-find-the-entitymodelcodegenerator-custom-tool Install VS2008 SP1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per LukLed and his link -- This requires VS2008 SP1.